# How to place two <g> side by side in an svg?

Tags: html, svg

Hello all I am new to html5 and svg tag.I want to ask a question about svg html element.
Here is my code

```
<html>
 <div>
   <svg width = "1335" height = "400">
     // I want to have two svg:g side by side one of more width and second of less width
        such that width of svg = first g + second g
      <g>
          // All the elements inside g should have same width as g
      </g>
      <g>
      </g> 
   </svg>
 <div>
</html>
```

I have tried it using transform.But failed.
Is it possible to have two g elements side by side as I can't set x and y of g ?
Can any one guide me of doingthis another way.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a transform, the problem then is how to get such values that make the transformed `g` at the `right` place. A possible way (the simplest, really) is to get the difference between coordinates of bounding boxes. Say you have a bounding box BB1 for group G1 and BB2 for G2, you could compute a translation to be applied to G2.

Of course we need a script to do that computation runtime. Such script will use

```
var BB1 = document.getElementById("G1").getBBox()
```

Here the code

```
<svg>
    <script>
        function align(evt) {
            var G1 = document.getElementById("G1")
            var G2 = document.getElementById("G2")
            var BB1 = G1.getBBox()
            var BB2 = G2.getBBox()
            G2.setAttribute("transform", "translate("+ ((BB1.x+BB1.width)-BB2.x) + " " + ((BB1.y+BB1.height)-BB2.y) + ")")
        }
    </script>                
    <g id="G1">
        <rect fill="red" x="10" y="10" width="40" height="30" />
    </g>
    <g id="G2" onclick="align(evt)">
        <rect fill="blue" x="70" y="60" width="100" height="50" />
    </g>
</svg>
```

you can experiment on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c2xbE/) with it

Answer (score 0):

The `<g>` element doesn't have a position or a size, that's why you can't set `x` and `y`, it's just a logical container.  Also SVG doesn't really have concept of layout in the same way as HTML does, which is what it looks like you're trying to achieve.  If you want two elements next to each other, [just draw them next to each other](http://jsfiddle.net/robertc/xsxPH/):

```
<svg width = "1335" height = "400">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="667" height="400" fill="#0f0"/>
    <rect x="668" y="0" width="667" height="400" fill="#00f"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: You can use a `transform` attribute on a <g> if you want though.

Comment: @ErikDahlström Yes, but as the `<g>` in itself has no position or size, the transform only visibly affects its children.  You couldn't transform the children of `<g>` so that they all fitted into a 'left column' unless you first knew the positions and sizes of all the children.

Comment: You're right - a transform doesn't define a viewport or a layout region of any kind. I'm only trying to point out that while the <g> may not have an x or a y attribute, it can in fact be positioned by a transform. Feel free to update your answer, and I'll remove my comments.

Answer (score 0):

If you just enclose each `<g>` in a separate `SVG` tag, and then close the set of SVG fragments within a `<section>` tag, the renderings with lay out just like images...flowing to the right and wrapping for me and my CSS--I can disect the CSS to figure out how/why if you really need that.

Answer (score 0):

the simple example of how to do Irish flag by SVG

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>Irish Flag SVG image</h1>
        <svg version="1.1"
             baseprofile="full"
             width="300" height="200"  
             xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

            <!--creating rect side by side for irish flag -->
            <rect x="0" y="0" width="300" height="200" fill="green"/>
            <rect x="100" y="0" width="300" height="400" fill="white"/>
            <rect x="200" y="0" width="300" height="400" fill="orange"/>
        </svg>

    </body>
</html>
```